# nodejs + documentdb warm up error

Tags: node.js, express, azure-cosmosdb

I've been trying to add DocumentDb support to my node.js Express application like it's explained in here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-nodejs-application/

Now if a user makes a request immediately after application's start she's getting an error because I suppose my DocumentDb database isn't ready yet.

What I want here is to make my user wait as database initialization is getting done.. how can I achieve this or what is a general approach in node.js to handle initialization that takes a place during the application's start?

```
var express = require('express');
....

var DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
var config = require('./config');
var StoryDao = require('./models/storyDao');
var Home = require('./controllers/home');

var docDbClient = new DocumentDBClient(config.endPoint, {
    masterKey: config.authKey
});

var storyDao = new StoryDao(docDbClient, config.databaseId, config.storyCollectionId);
var home = new Home(storyDao);
storyDao.init();
....
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('app started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

Comment: Put `app.listen` inside the ready callback of your dao

Comment: thanks, @Prinzhorn ! it was the first thing that came to my mind. but in that case I'm just getting a service unavailable error..

Comment: An error from Azure or inside your app?

Comment: @Prinzhorn neither inside my app or azure because app hasn't stat to listen yet and there is nothing to handle request I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Standing up a DocumentDB account is a one-time setup and should only take <5 minutes. The easiest thing to do is wait for it to finish.

Otherwise, you could set up a mock DAO... which would be useful from a unit testing perspective :)